# Issue with Nvidia graphic card and display resolution

Tags: nvidia

#### Translation:

I have an issue with my graphic card (Nvidia Quadro Fx 1400). When I go to *system information* this card is reported as *"unknown"* even though I installed nvidia-current drivers.

Now I can't adjust the screen resolution. It is now at 640x480 even though my display is capable of 1280x1024. It is a HP 1955 LCD. The display is also not recognized.

---

Bonjour,
J'ai un Problème avec ma carte-graphique (Nvidia Quadro Fx 1400)
lors j'allai o information système ! et  carte graphique ! je trouve qu'il est 'Inconnu'
et j'ai installer le  current version nvidia !
Et Je Peux Pas Ajuster la résolution d'écran ! Il Est a 640x480
et la résolution Que Mon Écran conseille s'est 1280x1024 !
Mon écran c'est HP 1955 LCD !
et aussi Mon écran Est Inconnu !
merci de Votre aide =)

Comment: Welcome to AU. Please note that this site is for questions and answers in English language only.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can be an solution (Ubuntu 12.04):
Go to System Settings > Hardware > Displays
Make sure that "Mirror displays" is not marked otherwise:
Note: may limit resolution options.
What is the result of the command "xrandr"in the terminal ?